# Pra que serve Options MultiViews?

Tags: htaccess

Vi um código `.htaccess` no Framework Laravel, cujo trecho co código tinha isso:

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
```

O que seria esse `-MultiViews`?
O que ele faz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Funcionalidade do MultiViews em sua Aplicação

Trata-se de uma regra de negociação de conteúdo do Apache.

O *MultiViews* habilitado para sua aplicação, oculta a extensão de um arquivo supondo que o mesmo seja um diretório.

Segue exemplos abaixo de como é utilizado o recurso quando funcionando em seu site:

1. No exemplo abaixo com o *MultiView* (desabilitado) você acessa seus arquivos do site `nome_do_arquivo.extensão`

   www.seusite.com.br/index.php
2. Com o recurso de *MultiView* (habilitado) seus arquivos, como `nome_do_arquivo.extensão` fica `nome_do_arquivo`, neste caso ocultando a extensão, como no exemplo abaixo:

   www.seusite.com.br/index

Para habilitar a função:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Para desabilitar a função:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

> **Nota**: Na configuração do Apache, utilizar `Options All` não habilita o opção `MultiViews` por padrão. O mesmo deve ser feito manualmente, se desejado.

### Como Funciona

Conforme a documentação oficial, o efeito de `MultiViews` é o seguinte: se o servidor recebe uma requisição para `/some/dir/foo`, se `/some/dir/` possui a opção `MultiViews` habilitada, e `/some/dir/foo` não existir, então o servidor lerá o diretório procurando arquivos nomeados com `foo.*`, efetivando um mapa de tipos que nomeia esses arquivos, atribuindo-lhes os mesmos tipos de mídia e codificação que teria se o cliente tivesse requisitado o arquivo pelo nome. Em seguida, o servidor escolhe a melhor correspondência com os requisitos da requisição.

Fontes: [Locaweb](https://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Ativando_o_MultiView_via_.htaccess), [Documentação oficial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#multiviews)

Answer (score 1):

Quando o MultiViews é habilitado em sua aplicação, isto ocultará a extensão de um arquivo. Seguem alguns exemplos abaixo de como é utilizado o recurso em seu site:

1) No exemplo abaixo com o MultiViews (desabilitado) você acessará os arquivos do site como: nome_do_arquivo.extensão

www.seusite.com.br/index.php

2) Com o recurso de MultiViews (habilitado) os arquivos do site como nome_do_arquivo.extensão ficarão como nome_do_arquivo, neste caso ocultando a extensão como no exemplo abaixo:

www.seusite.com.br/index